# FPDF not showing more than one image

Tags: javascript, pdf, vbscript, asp-classic, fpdf

Below is a little snippet which works fine, it shows me a PDF file, but with only the last image I set.

What is wrong in my code?
I didn't found documentation for ASP FPDF, only for PHP.
Any help is apreciated. Thanks!

```
<%@language=vbscript%>
<!--#include file="fpdf.asp"-->
<%Response.ContentType="application/pdf"%>

<%
imgCat = "..\fc_img\cat.jpg"
imgDog = "..\fc_img\dog.jpg"
Set pdf=CreateJsObject("FPDF")
pdf.CreatePDF "L", "mm", "A4"
pdf.SetPath("fpdf/")
pdf.Open()

pdf.AddPage()

pdf.SetTitle "Life is a b1tch"
pdf.Image imgDog , 10, 10, 20, 20
pdf.Image imgCat , 40, 40, 20, 20

pdf.Close()
pdf.Output()
%>
```

Comment: If you call AddPage between the Image calls do you get both images?

Comment: @safetyOtter, I get one image in each page, because AddPage adds another page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After researching this a bit, I've come to the conclusion that the ASP component version of FPDF has a bug that is causing this behaviour.

There is a interesting thread on [FPDF Library - PDF Generator](http://www.fpdf.org) site forum - [[ASP] Pb avec PDF de 2 pages](http://www.fpdf.org/phorum/read.php?f=1&i=31825&t=31825) which describes your exact problem and conclusion they come to is the ASP version of the FPDF component has a bug that is causing the issue.

<strike>Perhaps if you show us your `fpdf.asp` include file we might be able to help more,</strike> as the OP in the thread mentioned

> *"I solved it. I don't know how, but I solved it."*

suggests it is possible to fix.

---

**Edit:**

I think this maybe the what you are using [ASP FPDF](https://sites.google.com/site/aspfpdf/home) which is over 10+ years old and doesn't seem to be maintained.

```js
/****************************************************************************
*                                                                           *
* Software              : FPDF for Asp                                      *
* Version               : 1.01 beta                                         *
* Date                  : 2003/11/15                                        *
* Author                : Lorenzo Abbati                                    *
* License               : Freeware                                          *
* Site                  : http://www.aspxnet.it                             *
*                                                                           *
*****************************************************************************
*                                                                           *
* Author (PHP Class)    : Olivier Plathey                                   *
* Site (PHP Class)      : http://www.fpdf.org                               *
*                                                                           *
*****************************************************************************
*                                                                           *
* You may use and modify this software as you wish.                         *
*                                                                           *
****************************************************************************/
```

Latest download seems to be [v1.01](https://sites.google.com/site/aspfpdf/files/aspfpdf101.zip?attredirects=0)

The referenced website http://www.aspxnet.it doesn't seem to have anything useful.

---

In the past when it comes to Classic ASP I've found [AspPDF by Persits Software inc](http://www.asppdf.com) to be invaluable when building PDFs dynamically. It isn't free like ASP FPDF but it does work and is constantly updated and supported. Might be worth a look rather then trying to dig through the `fpdf.asp` to find the cause of the `.Image` bug.

---

**Update:**

Think the issue is with the `this._out` and the way the buffer is built, as this would explain why the one image is outputted and the other one isn't. For example if the buffer get's reset. Unfortunately the only way to work this out is to dig through the source code.

```js
this.Image=function Image(xfile , xx , xy , xw , xh , xtype , xlink)
{
  if (arguments.length<5){xh=0};
  if (arguments.length<6){xtype=""};
  if (arguments.length<7){xlink=""};

  if(!lib.isset(this.images[xfile]))
  {
    if(xtype=="")
    {
      xpos=lib.strrpos(xfile,".");
      if(!xpos)this.Error("Image file has no extension and no type was specified: " + xfile);
      xtype=lib.substr(xfile,xpos+1);
    }
    xtype=xtype.toLowerCase();
    if(xtype=="jpg" || xtype=="jpeg") xinfo=this._parsejpg(xfile);
    else this.Error("Unsupported image file type: " + xtype);

    xinfo["i"]=lib.count(this.images)+1;
    this.images[xfile]=xinfo;
  }
  else
    xinfo=this.images[xfile];

  if(xw==0)xw=xh*xinfo["w"]/xinfo["h"];
  if(xh==0)xh=xw*xinfo["h"]/xinfo["w"];

  this._out(lib.sprintf("q %.2f 0 0 %.2f %.2f %.2f cm /I%d Do Q",xw*this.k,xh*this.k,xx*this.k,(this.h-(xy+xh))*this.k,xinfo["i"]));
  if(xlink)this.Link(xx,xy,xw,xh,xlink);
}
```

Comment: I'm not into this problem anymore, but if someday I come back to it, I'll try this. Thanks